# Twilio Outgoing calls using web API

Tags: c#

I want to develop Application in C# using Twilio for outgoing calls. I have created Web API which returns XML and deployed it on Azure website. The URL which is generated I passed it in my code for making outgoing calls.

```
var call = client.InitiateOutboundCall(fromNumber, toNumber, "http://callpoc.azurewebsites.net/api/response");
```

but I am unable to change the voice of outgoing calls.

Answer (score 1):

Your TwiML (from the webhook above) is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>Hello Welcome in Auto call demo</Say>
</Response>
```

For changing voice you can set an attribute voice on `<Say>`, something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say voice="woman" language="English, India">Hello Welcome in Auto call demo</Say>
</Response>
```

You can read more on this at https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say